# How to revert the non lastest commit but still keep the head intact

Tags: git

Below is the my git history:

`commit-X: LOCAL HEAD which has not been push to remote
commit-A: The commit I want to undo and it is not push to remote yet.
commit-B: The REMOTE HEAD.`

It is possible to undo commit-A and still keep my LOCAL HEAD pointing to commit-X?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove commit-A while keeping the same changes under commit-x, one option is to run `git reset --soft HEAD~2`, which will remove the last 2 commits while keeping your files as they are. From here, you can reapply commit-x.

Answer (score 1):

You can try an interactive `rebase`, with `git rebase --interactive HEAD~2`

This will mark `HEAD` and the commit before it as up for rebase; for 3 commits, use `HEAD~3`, etc. This means you can change the commit itself, just the message, make more commits out of 1, make 1 commit out of many.

Practically, your default text editor will be brought up with the list of commits, and what action to take for each. Once you save the file (exit, or whatever), `git` will try to apply your changes.

If you want to **nuke** it, obliterate it completely, then you can simply *remove* the whole line of `commit-A`. Not touching the `commit-X` line means that `git` will re-apply the commit exactly as you made it (same changes, same message), without you having to do anything else.

Before doing any destructive `git` stuff, you could make it a habit to create a new branch where you are at the time. This way, if your commit surgery goes sideways, you can always get back to the original branch safely. For a broader safety net, check out [`git reflog`](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-reflog).

Be aware that changing a commit (messages, contents, etc) means that it has a new hash, and all the downstream commits (made after the changed one), will have to be redone. This is important, because, if you've already pushed to the remote before changing it, then you can't sync the remote, unless you do a `--force` push, but that will potentially make the other parties unhappy.